# Remove SQL Server database during uninstall of C# Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, sql-server-express

I have created a **MSI Installer** via **VS2010 Windows Installer**.

I am able to setup the C# program, and able to attach the database to SQL Server Express.

How can I remove the `.ldf` file in my program files and delete the DB created during attachment to the SQL Server Express when I do a uninstall of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute DROP DATABASE command in sql.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove the .ldf file in my program files and delete the DB created during attachment to
>   the ms sql express when I do a uninstall of my application?

Two words: CUSTOM ACTION. Protram a cusomto maction executed during uninstall.

Comment: Ok. I used this custom action to delete the files n folders. How can i delete the sql database created in mssql express that was created? Thanks.